# Why does the Alloy API not use the default scope for one signature if the scope for a different signature is specified?

Tags: alloy

I am currently attempting to run the following Alloy model on the Alloy Analyzer 5.1.0:

```
sig parent {}
sig var {}
pred testPred{}
run testPred for 3 parent
```

However, attempting to run this model results in the following syntax error:

**You must specify a scope for sig "this/var"**

Why is it not using the default scope for **var**? If the model is run with the command:

**run testPred**

It will find an instance using the default scope for both the signatures. Therefore, why would specifying the scope for signature **parent** stop the Alloy API from using the default scope for signature **var** and result in the syntax-error. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Well, the syntax is that you specify the default scope and then use `but [exactly]` to specify the scope of the sigs you want to have a different value for. For example:

```
run testPred for 3 but exactly 2 parent
```

The way you use the scope leaves the analyzer at loss for what you want.

1. in Alloy 6 `var` will be a keyword so you might want to use an alternative name.
2. the convention is to let sigs start with an upper case. If you're starting with this, it is usually best to follow the conventions.